# ¿Cómo desplegar sólo los registros con la hora más temprana y la más tarde de una fecha en particular?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada *eventos*:

| id | no_empleado | checada |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 100 | 2021-06-01 07:02:00 |
| 02 | 100 | 2021-06-01 07:03:00 |
| 03 | 100 | 2021-06-01 14:03:00 |
| 04 | 100 | 2021-06-01 14:04:00 |
| 05 | 200 | 2021-06-01 07:12:00 |
| 06 | 200 | 2021-06-01 07:13:00 |
| 07 | 200 | 2021-06-01 14:03:00 |
| 08 | 200 | 2021-06-01 14:04:00 |
| 09 | 100 | 2021-06-02 07:12:00 |
| 10 | 100 | 2021-06-02 07:13:00 |
| 11 | 100 | 2021-06-02 14:03:00 |
| 12 | 100 | 2021-06-02 14:04:00 |

Estoy tratando de que se me despliegue **solamente** la *checada* más temprana y la checada más tarde de cada fecha en particular y del *no_empleado* que específicamente deseo.

Digamos que quiero ver las entradas y salidas filtradas del empleado con el *no_empleado* **100**.  Debería obtener el siguiente resultado:

| no_empleado | checada |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2021-06-01 07:02:00 |
| 100 | 2021-06-01 14:04:00 |
| 100 | 2021-06-02 07:12:00 |
| 100 | 2021-06-02 14:04:00 |

¿Qué *query* me puede dar el resultado que busco?

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado / intentado y qué problemas concretos tienes en base a ello? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Voy a votar negativamente la pregunta porque, aunque esté bien redactada, no muestra esfuerzo de parte de OP para resolver el problema. Es una versión mejorada de "tengo esta tarea". Más información en el [centro de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

una forma de resolverlo es seleccionando los valores máximos y los valores mínimos de la fecha de evento, agrupando por empleado y por el valor de fecha (sin hora) del evento, teniendo esas dos consultas, puedes juntar ambos resultados con `UNION ALL`.

Tu consulta quedaría mas o menos así

```
SELECT `no_empleado`,MAX(`checada`) AS checada FROM `eventos` 
GROUP BY `no_empleado`, DATE(`checada`)
UNION ALL 
SELECT `no_empleado`,MIN(`checada`) AS checada FROM `eventos` c 
GROUP BY `no_empleado`, DATE(`checada`)
```

Aquí lo interesantes la forma de agrupamiento de solo la parte de la fecha. MySql lo permite, pero no se si funcione con otros motores.